# Detect if a json schema has a oneOf type schema

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to check if a schema has just a single schema in it or if it has several schemas within it with a oneOf property.

The python code should be something like this

```
If schema1 has oneOf property:
    Some code1
If schema1 is just a single schema:
    Some code2
```

Essentially I want to be able to distinguish between these 2 types of schemas

Schema1

```
"schema1": {
    "definitions": {
        "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Schema2

```
"schema2": {
    "definitions": {
        "schema": {
            "oneOf": [
            {
                "type": ["null"]
            },
            {
                "type": ["string"],
                "enum": ["NONE"]
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this in Python?

Edit: Corrected my example schema

Comment: The schemas look 'wrong' - are they the actual schemas you're working with ... if so  the objects themselves explicitly state which schema they are. If not .. please show the some sample data where you have to determine which schema is in place.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison I have corrected my example schema in the question. This is not the exact schema I'm using but is similar to it. Does my edits now rectify the schema or are they still wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example showing a way of recursively checking if there is a oneOf property in the json supplied. You'll need to check the parent property if you specifically want to only check the 'schema' portion of the json.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json


def objectHasKey(object_,key_):
    _result = False 
    if (type(object_)==dict):
        for _key in object_.keys():
            print _key
            if (type(object_[_key])==dict):
                _dict = object_[_key]
                _result = objectHasKey(_dict,key_)
            if _key == key_:
                _result = True
            if _result:
                break
    return _result

firstJSONText = '''
{
    "definitions": {
        "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'''

first = json.loads(firstJSONText)

secondJSONText = '''
{
    "definitions": {
        "schema": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": [
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": [
                        "string"
                    ],
                    "enum": [
                        "NONE"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
'''

second = json.loads(secondJSONText)

target = first

if objectHasKey(target,'oneOf'):
    print "Handle oneOf with first"
else:
    print "Handle default with first"

target = second

if objectHasKey(target,'oneOf'):
    print "Handle oneOf with second"
else:
    print "Handle default with second"
```

Example call with output

```
csmu-macbook-pro-2:detect-if-a-json-schema-has-a-oneof-type-schema admin$ ./test-for-schema.py 
definitions
schema
type
properties
name
type
Handle default with first
definitions
schema
oneOf
Handle oneOf with second
```

Comment: Just a quick note. From what I see in the code any "oneOf" is found down the tree. So it might not belong to the (sub)schema you are looking at. The code doesn't work with $ref.